# FDA Api Issue with Brackets

Tags: api, openfda

When I'm making what seems like a working query:

```
https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?api_key=123&search=report_date:[2021111+TO+20211112]
```

I get an error:

> [token_mgr_error] token_mgr_error: Lexical error at line 1, column
> 32. Encountered: "]" (93), after :

That same query works fine when done in browser but it's failing in my API tool. Any ideas?

Secondly, Is there another way to do a relative date or date range in the API if brackets simply can't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to urlencode() or a similar function in your server-side language to encode the special characters in your API URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).